# Android, GridLayout для 2.3 верии системы

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, вот у меня в интерфейсе используется GridLayout, который поддерживается с API 14, а есть ли способы как-то сделать чтобы GridLayout работал и на 10-11 API?

Мне говорили, что что-то нужно до установить, но я не понимаю, что и как.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно подключить к проекту `support library v7`. После этого используйте в коде и XML-layout'ах `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` вместо `android.widget.GridLayout`.

Comment: Можете вот это пояснить е в коде и XML-layout'ах android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout вместо android.widget.GridLayout

Это в каких xml? У меня сейчас один mail_layout.xml и там просто

<GridLayout и там всякие его свойства и т.д., что в него входит.

Comment: @Rumato вот вместо <GridLayout  напишите <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Comment: А вот ещё, тогда, когда я так пишу android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
у элементов, которые находятся в GridLayout, например вот 

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnDelete"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
 
ошибки


            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="3"

Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

может тоже как-то подругому описывать свойства?

Comment: Добавьте описание `namespace`'а, например, `app`:

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Затем замените у специфических для `GridLayout` атрибутов префикс с `android` на добавленный, в данном случае — `app`. То есть будут `app:layout_column`, `app:layout_row` и т.д.